# Can you prevent Visual Studio 2015 from raising to foreground when using "focus follow hover"?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using the "focus follow hover (without raise)" behavior (by editing the registry) but Visual Studio doesn't seem to abide by that rule. When I hover over the window it raises to the foreground which is very undesirable when I'm trying to access an app that isn't maximized above it.

Is there some setting or hack I can perform to fix this behavior?

*I couldn't decide weather or not to put this here or on SuperUser. Eventually decided here as it regards Visual Studio.*

Comment: Hmm. Using undocumented Windows feature causes program to behave unexpectedly. Not terribly surprising. Visual Studio isn't exactly known for complying with standard Windows UI guidelines anymore. I doubt anyone ever tested this.

Comment: It's technically documented https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957204.aspx ;). I just find it odd that a product by the same company who made the OS it's running on doesn't follow their own guidelines.